# Drop Down menu -- onmouseout getting invoked on the child node when set in the parent node

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, onmouseout

Trying to mimic the `browse catagories` in the following link https://dev.twitter.com/discussions

`onmouseover`  -- the container expands to fit the new items within itself -- but,moving the mouse within the container(expanded conainer) will result in the `onmouseout` getting invoked -- even when the mouse is within the container itself -- silly mistake or not trying hard to find out where and how i might be going wrong

Code --

```
<html>
    <style type="text/css">
    #container{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    }
    .contents{
    height: 30px;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    var foo = new Array("bar","santa","claus")
    function fire(){
    var contents = document.getElementById("contents")
    if(contents.hasChildNodes())
    return
    for(i = 0 ; i < foo.length ; i++){
        var tem=document.createElement("div");
        tem.setAttribute("id",'cont'+i);
        tem.setAttribute("class","contents");
        tem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(foo[i]))
        contents.appendChild(tem)
    }
    }
    function unfire(evt){

    if ((evt.target || evt.srcElement).id != "container") 
    return;

    var contents = document.getElementById("contents");
    while(contents.hasChildNodes())
    contents.removeChild(contents.firstChild)
    }
    </script>

    <div id="container" onmouseover="fire(event)" onmouseout="unfire(event)">
        Move your mouse here
        <div id="contents" ></div>
    </div>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I got my original answer completely wrong, I'm not sure what I was thinking.  Of course, `mouseout` fires on a parent when the mouse moves to a child.  In this case, you need to check the `relatedTarget` or `toElement` properties of the `event` object and check to see if that element is a descendant of the container.

You can check ancestry using `contains()` in Internet Explorer and `compareDocumentPosition()` in other browsers.  For example, change `onmouseout="unfire(event)"` to `onmouseout="unfire.call(this, event)"` and add the following code to the `unfire` function:

```
var to = evt.relatedTarget || evt.toElement;

if((this.contains && this.contains(to)) || this.compareDocumentPosition(to) & 16)
    return;
```

Comment: changed the code,but still when the mouse is moved to the items,i.e contents -- the `onmouseout` gets triggered - target being `container` itself though the mouse is within the container itself..!!

Comment: going through the link http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/bursting-the-event-bubble in which he says -- if you move the mouse into a child, this triggers the mouseout event on the parent. In this case, the target will match the parent  -- so,the answer you provided isnt working,and trying to figure out why this is so..

Comment: @Vivek: of course it does. Sorry, I managed to get that completely wrong and sent you on a wild goose chase. I've changed my answer to be more correct.

Comment: this is a window object,is it not ??.. and the items are not getting deleted at all now..

Comment: @Vivek: if you changed your `onmouseout="unfire(...` to `onmouseout="unfire.call(...` as per the updated answer, `this` should be the "container" object.  You might need to play around with the code, still checking `event.target || event.srcElement` to avoid the bubbling issue.  NB, it's much easier to work with events if you attach the handlers via JavaScript.

Comment: @Vivek: np; glad we got there in the end :-)

Comment: although i would like to know what the difference between `unfire` and `unfire.call(..` ?? ..

Comment: @VivekChandra: `call` sets the context (what the `this` object refers to) for a function.

Comment: ,great. .thank u for that.. was wondering why the this obj always pointed to the widnow obj.. thanks a ton,u've been a gr8 help..